# call Sub not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

Why this call of sub is not working properly?
I get an error that there are undefined objects.
I believe this can be a little problem but cannot find a solution.
I am trying to make new sheetnames but the code is too long for VBA , so I have to split the code, and continue in a second Sub. (apparently it is limited to 15 of 16 handlings)

Thanks in advance.

below my startcode

```
   Sub Macro1()
   ' Macro1 Macro
   Dim wbNew As Workbook
   'sheet 1----------------------------------------------------------------
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
   Range("A1:S53").Select
   Range("S53").Activate
   Selection.Copy

   Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    wbNew.Sheets(1).Activate
   Range("A1:S53").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    wbNew.Sheets(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Range("A15").Select


    Call vanaf_17

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Path\" & "per 1-15" & " " & Format(Range("C13"), "mmmm") & " " & Format(Range("C13"), "YYYY") & ".xlsx"
     FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWindow.Close

  End Sub
```

code to call

```
 Sub vanaf_17()
 Dim wbNew As Workbook
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'sheet 17----------------------------------------------------------------
'here starts a new sheet!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A1:S53").Select
Range("S53").Activate
Selection.Copy

'change here sheet nr!!!!!!!
wbNew.Sheets(17).Activate
Range("A1:S53").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'change here sheet nr!!!!!!!
wbNew.Sheets(17).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


'Here ends a new sheet!!!!!

 End Sub
```

Comment: You never set wbNew...`'change here sheet nr!!!!!!!
wbNew.Sheets(17).Activate` in the second macro

Comment: I Set it in the first code as   Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add , but in second code how do I wright that please?

Comment: You have to name the workbook in the first code, then set the workbook in the second code. Is activeworkbook and wbNew different workbooks?

Comment: the  workbook name is Thisworkbook (but not set it), wbnew is the new created workbook, when I select active workbook it is also referring to thisworkbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set `wbnew` in that second sub as well. The second sub has no idea what you mean when you say `wbnew`. When you have a variable in a subroutine or function it exists only in the subroutine or function. As soon as you move to another subroutine, your variables are 100% worthless.

To get around this, you can pass parameters between subs.

When you start your second sub `Sub vanaf_17()` Do it like so:

```
Sub vanaf_17(wbNew as Workbook)
    ....your code
End Sub
```

When you call `vanaf_17()` do it like so:

```
Call vanaf_17 webNew
```

Also, since you are declaring `webNew` as a workbook in the parameters, delete the `dim wbNew as Workbook` bit in `vanaf_17` otherwise you'll get an error.

Lastly, There is no reason why you need to split these up into two subroutines. I've never heard of '15 or 16 handling' limit and I'm not real sure what that means. I've seen some ugly ass recorded macro code that goes on for thousands of lines of `.select` and `.activate` and `oh-my-god-no-that-is-such-a-bad-idea` for what feels like forever. Excel can handle it.

Updated: Here is what the code would look like with this change:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' Macro1 Macro
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    'sheet 1----------------------------------------------------------------
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A1:S53").Select
    Range("S53").Activate
    Selection.Copy

    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    wbNew.Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A1:S53").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    wbNew.Sheets(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Range("A15").Select


    Call vanaf_17 wbNew

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Path\" & "per 1-15" & " " & Format(Range("C13"), "mmmm") & " " & Format(Range("C13"), "YYYY") & ".xlsx"
     FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub

Sub vanaf_17(wbNew AS Workbook) 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'sheet 17----------------------------------------------------------------
    'here starts a new sheet!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A1:S53").Select
    Range("S53").Activate
    Selection.Copy

    'change here sheet nr!!!!!!!
    wbNew.Sheets(17).Activate
    Range("A1:S53").Select

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    'change here sheet nr!!!!!!!
    wbNew.Sheets(17).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    'Here ends a new sheet!!!!!

 End Sub
```

That being said, there are some changes here that I think will help. Namely, you could loop through all the sheets that you care about in thisWorkbook, and call your subroutine to copy and paste the `A1:S53` range into a new worksheet in the new workbook. Below I have a quick example of what that would look like. I kept some of the unnecessary `.select` and `.activate` stuff in there, because I figured this change was dramatic enough. You'll see that all of your sheet creation and copying/pasting is now done in the second subroutine. The first subroutine just sets up the new workbook, loops through the sheets, and then saves the new workbook.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' Create a new workbook. Then loop through each worksheet in this workbook (that we care about)
    '   and call the CreateNewWS subroutine to copy the A1:S53 range for each worksheet into the
    '   new workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create a new workbook, assign it to wbNew variable
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

    'Loop through all the sheets in the current workbook that we care about
    Dim sheetname as string
    For each sheetname in Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3", "sheet4")

        'call the CreateNewWS subroutine to do the sheet creation and copying and pasting
        call CreateNewWS wbNew, thisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname)

    Next sheetname

    'You could also loop through all of the worksheets in thisworkbook if you want to copy every worksheet:
    'Dim ws as worksheet
    'For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    '   call CreateNewWS wbNew, ws
    'Next ws

    'Save the new workbook
    newWb.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "C:\Path\" & "per 1-15" & " " & Format(Range("C13"), "mmmm") & " " & Format(Range("C13"), "YYYY") & ".xlsx"
     FileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    'Close the new workbook
    newWb.Close

    'Don't forget to turn this back on. Yikes.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub CreateNewWS(wbNew AS Workbook, ws as Worksheet) 

    'This subroutine takes in the wbNew and the worksheet (ws) that we are copying from.
    '   it copys range A1:S53 from the ws to the wbNew's new worksheet.


    'This will hold the new worksheet we are adding to the wbNew
    Dim wsNew as worksheet

    'Add a new worksheet to the new workbook
    wbNew.Activate
    set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

    'Activate and copy from current workbook
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1:S53").Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Activate and paste into newWb      
    wsNew.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


 End Sub
```

I haven't really tested this change, but the guts of it are accurate. If you do decide to switch over to this type of logic and you run into errors, it would be prudent to create a new stackoverflow question to work through the problem.

Comment: https://app.box.com/s/dyzdsdqijzebzaq99cv7uzmgq4wg7u2u   This is how I puzzeld the code that was Too long. VBA is writing that after an error occurs?

Comment: this should be 1 long code ,from sheet 1 to sheet 30

Comment: It is working with the split code now. Maybe it is not the most presentable code , but it is doiing the job. I am verry verry happy with that :-)

Comment: If that is ok with you I would like to mark this post as solved :-). Ill wait for your feedback.

Comment: I understand now. You have many subroutines, of which vanaf_17() is just one. Sort of like one for each sheet you want to copy? Assuming that's correct, I rewrote your subroutines to do this logic for every sheet. So you just need the two routines instead of your main routine for Sheet1 and Workbook creation/save, and then 30 more subroutines that are just copy and pastes of eachother.

Comment: indeed. Starting from my workbook (thisworkbook sheet "1") I have 1 sheet where I have to extract 30 names, then copy them in a copy of a blanc sheet sheet(1) of thisworkbook to a new workbook.

Comment: I can use your suggested looping in a code of my next question  .                                                                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478394/extract-data-from-excel-workbook-with-specific-procedure-to-report-sheet